# Python3 If Else statement SyntaxError and IndentationError

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, if-statement, stdin

I am new to Python and Stackoverflow. I tried looking at some of the already existing questions, but I could not see where I was messing up. Sorry in advance for the repeated question.

I am trying to figure out what I did wrong with my if-else statement.

**Here is what I wrote:**

```
myFavoriteFood = "Ice Cream"
userGuess = input("What is my favorite food? ")

if myFavoriteFood == userGuess:
    print("nice!")

else:
    print("Sorry, that's not right. Try again!")
```

**Here is the Error I am getting:**

```
>>> else:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    else:
    ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>     print("Sorry, that's not right. Try again!")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("Sorry, that's not right. Try again!")
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
>>>
```

**What I have tried so far:**

- To avoid any more spacing issues, I just let Visual Studio Code add the indent.
  I tried with 4 space only. I tried with tab. I never mixed the two. I still ran into the issue.
- I didn't realize I needed ":", so I added those.
- I tried "else :" but that errored.
- I made sure there was no extra space in front of if or else.
- I tried enclosing the codeblock in parentheses but that errored.
- VSC says Line 5 Col 1-5 is 4 spaces; as well as, Line 8 Col 1-5 is 4 spaces.

**What I am confused about:**

- Why are the line numbers off from the error? Am I reading this wrong?
- What am I doing wrong in the if-else part?
- Did I do something wrong with input? Maybe that's causing an issue? I only ask because of the stdin in the error log. I am assuming/guessing that's something long like "standard text something input". Idk.

---

**General Info:**
I am working on Windows 10 at the moment. I am using Visual Studio Code with the terminal that is built inside. My program is saved as .py. I am running Python. 3.10.0 64bit. I have selected Python because I work on both Mac and Windows, and I wanted something that could work on both platforms.

(I hope this is info is helpful and not even more confusing.)

Comment: "File "<stdin>", line 1" - looks like you are pasting the line into the interpreter prompt somehow; this `else:` should be line 7 or so, not line 1

Comment: I tested your code here, and it's running normally. Probably a VS Code error

Comment: I think the problem is that you're pasting this code in your python console, and that there is a whole blank line before the `else`. So, the console thinks your previous code is terminated and you're starting a new one. And you cannot _start_ a code with a `else:`

Comment: @RandomDavis Thank you Thank you! That makes sense! Thank you everyone for helping